# detect when application using permissions ~ Android

Tags: android, android-permissions

I list all permissions of the new installed application on Android device. But I want to detect when an application uses these permission. For example, I installed an app and it uses READ_CALENDAR permission. It is not always read my calendar data. I want to detect the time it reads my calendar data. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think this is possible.  You would need to be able to monitor each external app, and you don't have the ability to know what they are doing (due to security restrictions on Android).  In other words, your app doesn't have the ability to monitor the actions of other apps (not written by you) on the device.

I don't think you have access to the system at the level you would need to perform this (this may be possible on a Rooted phone, but I think that would still be difficult).

Comment: yeah I am asking for rooted phone.

Comment: Either way, I still think you are not going to be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

When you write an app you have to insert in the android manifest all the possible "uses permissions", for all the functionality that your app will use. 
When someone installs your app, before the installation procedure, he can read all the permissions used from the app. If you accept to install it, the app will use all those permissions listed.

Comment: He is asking how to detect, during runtime, when a Permission is used.

Comment: ok i accept these permissions at the beginning but, I want to detect the exact time when it using this permissions. It is not always using these permissions.

Comment: During the app runtime, all the permissions that you accepted are used. Maybe in a passive way, but if you start the app, all the permissions start. If you want to create a list of them you may use something like that: PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager(); 
and then List<PermissionGroupInfo> lstGroups = pm.getAllPermissionGroups(0);

Comment: You can do something like that: when an object or function that requires a special "uses permission" is instantiated, you may write in the logcat something like "start the GPS location" and when the object is captured from the garbage collector you can write in the logcat "stop the GPS location". Maybe it is not a perfect way to reach your purpose, but it is a good point. :-)

Comment: @MachoProgrammer yeah I did List<PermissionGroupInfo>. actually i'm not asking this. If program uses READ_CALENDAR permission, is it take calendar data at all times? I will try your second way thanks;)

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure about that. The program starts the READ_CALENDAR permission and you can use the object CalendarContract.*.